# find a string and update 4th field in unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to find a string and update 4th filed in a | seperated file in Unix.I have below sample file.

```
ROSE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
YELLOW.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
BLUE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
```

Search the string `YELLOW.2017` and if find then update corresponding line 4th field with `YES`
I want below result.

```
ROSE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
YELLOW.2017|D|5:00 AM|YES|||
BLUE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
```

I am using below command and getting below wrong result.

```
nawk -F'|' '$1=="'$fname'"{$4="YES"}1' filename.txt > filename1.txt
```

where `fname=YELLOW.2017`

wrong result:

```
ROSE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
YELLOW.2017 D 5:00 AM YES
BLUE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
```

My Unix version is SunOS 5.10

Comment: Maybe you need to format your text to make it look more coherent.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit a record, it gets rebuilt and field separators get updated with output field separator (OFS) so you need to set that also.

Another way to get the value of `$fname` to your script is to set an awk variable to its value (`-v fname="$fname"`):

```
$ fname="YELLOW.2017"
$ awk -v fname="$fname" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==fname{$4="YES"}1' file
ROSE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
YELLOW.2017|D|5:00 AM|YES|||
BLUE.2017|D|5:00 AM||||
```